# Change CSS Style of another HTML file using a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the CSS style of another HTML file using a form. This is what I got so far however, the code isn't working as it won't change the style of the uploaded HTML file.

Here is my main code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Changing the style of another HTML File</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateSize() {
      var nBytes = 0,
          oFiles = document.getElementById("uploadInput").files,
          nFiles = oFiles.length;
      for (var nFileId = 0; nFileId < nFiles; nFileId++) {
        nBytes += oFiles[nFileId].size;
      }
      var sOutput = nBytes + " bytes";
      // optional code for multiples approximation
      for (var aMultiples = ["KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB"], nMultiple = 0, nApprox = nBytes / 1024; nApprox > 1; nApprox /= 1024, nMultiple++) {
        sOutput = nApprox.toFixed(3) + " " + aMultiples[nMultiple] + " (" + nBytes + " bytes)";
      }
      // end of optional code
      document.getElementById("fileNum").innerHTML = nFiles;
      document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = sOutput;
    }

    function extract() {
    var el = document.getElementById("test");
    el.style.background = 'green';
    el.style.color = 'red';
    }
    </script>

    <body onload="updateSize();">
    <form>
    <p><input id="uploadInput" type="file" name="myFiles" onchange="updateSize();" multiple> selected files: <span id="fileNum">0</span>; total size: <span id="fileSize">0</span></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="extract()"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The file which is being uploaded:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
#test {
background-color: blue;
color: yellow;
};
</style>
</head>

<body> 
<div id="test">This is a div</div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Where I'm I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what `document` refers to, and how file uploads work. Your `extract` function is indeed called when the user presses the button. (Although it may be pressed when there are no files, what do you do then?)

But even inside the function, `document` still refers to the same `document`, the one with `<title>Changing the style of another HTML File</title>` and the file input form. It looks for an element with id `#test`, which it cannot find in this `document`, then fails, because it cannot set the `style` attribute of a non-existent / `null` element.

What you seem to *want* to do is to:

1. Let the user provide HTML files via the form input.
2. Parse the uploaded files as HTML.
3. Edit the CSS contained within (which involves first parsing the CSS, then editing it, then re-encoding it.)
4. Saving the files.

None of these are simple and they all have their subtleties. Parsing HTML is hard, but there are libraries that can manage this for you. Likewise for CSS. Saving is another problem – do you want to create another file that the user can then download? You cannot modify a user's file – consider if websites could simply modify the contents of your hard disk. It would be a security disaster.

Perhaps the most important question you should ask yourself is – why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I'm going to try my best to do what is described above. If you know any tutorials, please do link them to me. @Aurel Bily